# Permutation with regard to rearranging words

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of the letters of
the word **REMAND** is possible if they have **REM** together in any order?

The answer shows $^3P_ 3 \times  \, ^4P_4 = 144$

I get that the $^3P_3$ part because there are $6$ possible ways to arrange REM, however, why should the second part of the answer be $^4P_4$, shouldn't it be $^3P_3$ since only three letters are left to be arranged?

Thank you!

Comment: but REMAND  contains 6 letters though doesn't hat mean after REM the second part should dbe 5 P 5?

Comment: No, try this small trick tie the letters REM with a rope and call it  X the REM can change internally in X in 6 ways. Now on the outside we have XAND which can be arranged in 4! ways. Hence 6*4!

Comment: @NewGuy ahh That makes sense now thank you!

Comment: Check out generalized Dyck words. They compute the number of arrangements avoiding a certain pattern, i.e. the number of distinct words avoiding REM in your case. You can substract that to the total amount of arrangements.

Comment: @NewGuy You should turn your comment into an answer.